# Rendering JSON object to AJAX calls in grails

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, grails

I am trying to auto-populate employee details on entering employee number.

In the controller I am calling a method that returns JSON object:

```
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    System.out.println(gson.toJson(objEmp));
    return gson.toJson(objEmp);
```

In the controller I am returning to AJAX call as:

```
render(contentType: "application/json") {[data]}
```

AJAX call is as follows:

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
if(e.which == 13){
    var URL="${createLink(controller:'employeeAdd',action:'getDetails')}";
    var empNo = $("#empNo").val(); 
    alert("empNo: " + empNo);
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url:URL,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",            
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            empNo:empNo
        },
           success: function (data) {

              $("#empNo").val(data.employeeNumber);
              $("#employeeName").val(data.employeeName);
           },
           error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
               var msg = '';
               if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                   msg = 'Not connect.\n Verify Network.';
               } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                   msg = 'Requested page not found. [404]';
               } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                   msg = 'Internal Server Error [500].';
               } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                   msg = 'Requested JSON parse failed.';
               } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                   msg = 'Time out error.';
               } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                   msg = 'Ajax request aborted.';
               } else {
                   msg = 'Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText;
               }

           },     
    });
};
});
```

I am not getting any error. Also nothing is auto populated even though data is present in JSON format. I am new to JSON and AJAX calls. I tried codes from internet still I couldn't get the desired output. I am unable to find the error. Any pointers will be of great help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I made the following changes and the code worked:

1. Returned employee object from method.
2. Rendered the object as JSON ==> render dataEmp as JSON
3. Extracted data in AJAX call funtion ==> success: function (dataEmp)